# Securely send passwords from login form in Flask

Tags: python, flask, hash, passwords

I have a website with a simple login function using sessions. I thought it was secure because I was hashing and salting the passwords, but I have realised that what's actually (probably) happening is that I am sending the plaintext password in a POST request to the server, and only then am I hashing and salting it. I thought I understood how to manage passwords, but now I'm wondering what to do.

Here's my code:

```
import bcrypt
from argon2 import PasswordHasher, exceptions
import db as database

ph = PasswordHasher()


@app.route("/login", methods=["POST", "GET"])
def login():
    if check_logged_in(session, 0):
        return redirect("/index")
    else:
        error = ""  # set to nothing unless we get error below
        if request.method == "POST":  # if user submits form
            username = request.form["username"]  # retrieve username from form
            password = request.form["password"]  # retrieve password from form
            if verify_login(username, password):  # if their login is valid
                session["username"] = username  # update session with their username and redirect them to index
                return redirect("/index")
            error = "Invalid username or password"  # else update the error message
        return render_template("login.html", error=error)  # and return login with error message


def verify_login(username, password):
    db_hash, salt = database.retrieve_pw_salt(username)  # gets hashed/salted password and salt from database given a username
    if db_hash is None:
        return False  # invalid username
    try:
        ph.verify(db_hash, salt + password)
        return True  # valid username and password
    except exceptions.VerifyMismatchError:
        return False  # invalid password


def check_logged_in(session, required_privilege):
    if "username" not in session:
        return False  # not logged in
    elif session["username"] == "admin":
        return True  # logged in as admin
    elif session["username"] == "reception" and required_privilege <= 1:  # checks to ensure a reception isn't trying to access admin pages/features
        return True  # logged in as reception
    elif session["username"] == "teacher" and required_privilege == 0:  # checks to ensure a teacher isn't trying to access admin/reception pages/features
        return True  # logged in as teacher
    return False  # else not logged in
```

I guess I thought that this code would be running on the client side but I don't think it is. In that case, how can I get the salt for my user onto the client side and then combine that with the password, hash it and only then send it to my server?

My server is running Nginx with uWSGI on Ubuntu 18.04 if that makes a difference.

Thanks.

EDIT: This is how I generated the salts in the first place by the way:

```
def generate_salt():  # creates a salt
    salt = bcrypt.gensalt().decode("utf-8")
    return salt
```

Comment: The normal solution is to use a secure channel (i.e. https) for posting login credentials.

Comment: https:// all the things!

Comment: You're confusing two different security models. Hashing and salting protects your users' passwords if the database is leaked. In terms of preventing MITM attacks stealing your users' login details, it doesn't matter which side of the connection it's hashed on - if someone could grab the password in transit, they could grab the hash in transit.

Comment: @thebjorn I am using HTTPS but I thought this was used as well. Could you read my comment on the answer below and see what you think?

Answer (score 3):

> I am using HTTPS but I thought this was used as well.

All security measures need to have a clear concept of what they will protect you from, and what you need to do depends on which attack vectors you're trying to cover.

Your concern seems to be that someone can read the password in-transit:

> but I have realised that what's actually (probably) happening is that
>   I am sending the plaintext password in a POST request to the server

You are incorrect though, when you say that the password is sent as plain text when you're using https. Https means that the channel between the server and the browser is encrypted, and.. considered safe(*). Encrypting twice doesn't add any security even though it may seem like doing more work should give you "something".

If you're trying to protect against an attacker that has control over the browser or client machine, then no amount of client side encryption will help; the situation is the same if you're trying to protect against an attacker that has control over the server.

One situation that can leak passwords is unhandled exceptions during the POST. Most web-apps report such errors either through email or services such as Sentry. Web-frameworks usually have a way of mitigating this that are more general, and easier to work with, than client side encryption (e.g. Django's `@sensitive_post_parameters(...)` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/error-reporting/#django.views.decorators.debug.sensitive_post_parameters).

One situation where you would use client side encryption is if the user wants to store/retrieve data on the server that the server-admin shouldn't be able to read. The server can't interact with the data, so it's not a use case for passwords during login.

(*) if you want to protect against someone that can decrypt an https channel then you're way outside what's needed for login-form for normal websites (and if you're working for the NSA you should probably ask internally rather than on SO ;-)

ps: you probably shouldn't decode('utf-8') the result of `bcrypt.gensalt()` -- I haven't looked, but I can't imagine it returns utf-8 data.

addendum: not all binary data is utf-8. `base64` is one way to create a unicode representation:

```
>>> b = b'\xc3\x28'   # byte sequence that is not valid utf-8
>>> b.decode('utf-8')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 0: invalid continuation byte
>>> import base64
>>> base64.b64encode(b)
b'wyg='
>>> base64.b64encode(b).decode('ascii')
'wyg='
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I guess I'm concerned that say the server were to be hacked, they would be able to read user's passwords in plaintext. I think that when the user logs in I should make a query to my server for their salt, then on the client side I hash the salt and their password, then I send that to the server where I compare the two and allow/deny access based on the result. That way, if anyone gains access to my server or somehow manages to decrypt the request, the user's password is not revealed. Is that not what big companies such as Facebook, Reddit etc. do?

Comment: Also, with regards to decoding the salt, I did that because it produces a bytes object but I didn't know how to store that in my MYSQL database so I just made it a string. It seems to be working but is that something I should change? How?

Comment: If someone gets control of your server they can log the user in without a password, and they can send a loginform that is completely different from the one you've designed (including completely different javascript). You _should_ salt and encrypt the password before storing it to disk that way it is encrypted both at rest (salted/encrypted/stored in server db) and in transit (https).

Comment: I am hashing their password + a salt before I store them. However, if they gain access to the server then they will be able to intercept plaintext passwords after they have been received by my server from the HTTPS POST request, which is much worse than them just being able to use the user's account.

Comment: A decode operation, `x.decode('utf-8')`, gives you a Unicode object created from interpreting the bytes in `x` as validly encoded utf-8 data. A salt function generally generates binary data and there is absolutely no reason to believe that this data is always valid utf-8.  You should either store this in an appropriate database field (e.g. binary / varbinary), or e.g. convert it to base64 (an encoding that can handle random binary data) before storing it.

Comment: If they gain access to the server... they can send a _different_ login form... a form that _does_ _not_ contain your fancy client side salt+crypt... thus receiving the passwords in plain text regardless of any effort you've made.  If someone gains access to the server you can assume that any code you write is not the code received by the client (even if it can look the same to the end-user).

Comment: I tried `salt = base64.b64encode(bcrypt.gensalt())` but it still produces a bytes object. What am I missing?

Comment: That's true, but I guess it's still more effort on the attacker's part and therefore more secure.

Comment: Ah I didn't realise https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/binary-varbinary.html existed, I suppose there's no need then I will just store them directly as binary(29).

Comment: `base64` gives you a bytes object where the individual bytes are in the ascii range, thus you can `base64.b64encode(bcrypt.gensalt()).decode('ascii')` to get a Unicode string.

Comment: I see, and since I can't concatenate a string and a bytes object I shouldn't just leave it as a bytes object.

Comment: The amount of extra effort on the attacker's part is negligible. If client side encryption had been a real winner you'd see more people doing it. It really does not offer any added security, sorry. Nobody is stopping you from doing it, but you'd add more security by investing in an IDS.

Comment: But what about malicious employees? Surely companies like the ones I mentioned earlier don't allow anyone with access to any of their servers to just view user's passwords in plaintext?

Comment: Employees should only get the access rights necessary for their position, so if the attack vector you want to defend against is malicious employees, the standard solution is through OS permissions, audit logs, the employee handbook, and your hiring process. Such an attack vector cannot be left to handle by application developers every time they want to write a login form. Malicious programmers as an attack vector are handled by the above + code-review + testing... Most of these issues have been thought about deeply by people with much more experience than you and I, better build on their work.

Answer (score 2):

From an attacker's point of view, client-side hashing provides no additional security. See https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/62280/client-side-hashing-of-password-before-sending-it-from-login-form

Comment: If you can confirm that the source of the salt is really the server and not a man in the middle? So basically you would need a secured and authenticated connection anyway.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, but I was wondering the same thing, so I thought I should share what I discovered with people who might find it later.

Most websites do not alter the passwords on the client side. There are two reasons for this.

1. There really isn't much support for client side hashing. Javascript doesn't have support for SHA, for example.
2. Hashing client side doesn't actually make the site that much more secure. A MITM attacker can alter the javascript and simply turn off the hashing. So, in reality, it would only help against passive peeks.

Here are some threads that helped me understand:
https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/53594/why-is-client-side-hashing-of-a-password-so-uncommon
https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/42062/how-do-you-verify-if-an-app-is-using-secure-comms